# Installing prettytensor for TensorFlow not working on OSX

Tags: python, installation, pip, tensorflow, prettytensor

I can't install `prettytensor`. I've tried doing it through `pip` and also by installing the sourcecode and doing `python setup.py install` in the directory.

**I updated my `tensorflow` . Does anyone have any idea on how I can install `prettytensor` on my machine?**

```
pip install prettytensor
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): prettytensor in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/prettytensor-0.6.0-py2.7.egg
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): enum34>=1.0.0 in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from prettytensor)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.10.0 in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from prettytensor)
Collecting tensorflow>=0.7.1 (from prettytensor)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow>=0.7.1 (from prettytensor) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow>=0.7.1 (from prettytensor)
```

when i try to import `prettytensor`

```
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:57:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> import prettytensor as pt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Mu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/prettytensor-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/prettytensor/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from prettytensor import funcs
  File "/Users/Mu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/prettytensor-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/prettytensor/funcs.py", line 25, in <module>
    from prettytensor.pretty_tensor_image_methods import *
  File "/Users/Mu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/prettytensor-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/prettytensor/pretty_tensor_image_methods.py", line 20, in <module>
    from prettytensor import layers
ImportError: cannot import name layers
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check a version of tensorflow.

If your tensorflow is not 0.7.1, you can upgrade like below.

(see also https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/get_started/os_setup.html)

```
# Mac OSX, CPU only:
$ pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.7.1-cp27-none-any.whl
```

Then install prettytensor again.

```
$ pip uninstall prettytensor
$ pip install prettytensor
```

For your reference.
Here is my results.(OSX 10.11.3)

```
In [1]: import tensorflow as tf

In [2]: tf.__version__
Out[2]: '0.7.1'

In [3]: import prettytensor as pt

In [4]: pt.PrettyTensor
Out[4]: prettytensor.pretty_tensor_class.PrettyTensor
```

Comment: That worked. At first I got an error w/ my setuptools, then I got an error w/ protobuf.  A combination of your post and https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1244 solved the issue.

Comment: That didn't work for me, I'm not sure what version of prettytensor that is supposed to install, I am using tf 0.7.1 from here https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags/?page=1&ordering=-last_updated I also tried different versions and had different problems with importing prettytensor sadly. I am trying to reproduce OpenAI infogan results but can't replicate their system configuration...

Comment: hi @BrunoCL . What kind of errors did you see when importing prettytensor? When I tried with tf-2.4.0-rc0 and prettytensor-0.7.4, I got the AttributeError because some keys are deprecated in tensorflow-2.x. Therefore I modified `import tensorflow as tf` to `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf; tf.disable_v2_behavior`, these errors are solved. I hope this is helpful.